# what is the meaning of "buzzing with posibilities"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I want to know the meaning of "buzzing with posibilities" for example in a sentence like this:

> The Richmond Coliseum was buzzing with pre-game possibilities Friday.

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buzz+with

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer *...was **abuzz** with...,* but I see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+buzzing+with%2Cwas+abuzz+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20buzzing%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20abuzz%20with%3B%2Cc0) that the rest of the English-speaking world hasn't *quite* caught up with me on that one yet (in the *written* form, at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Buzzing" here is used metaphorically. "Buzz" is the sound bees make. You do not normally hear a single bee unless it is very close to you, but the buzzing is very noticeable if you are anywhere near a swarm or a hive. Moreover, if you are near a a hive on a warm sunny day, the air is thronged with flying bees.

So one metaphorical use of "buzzing with X" means "in the midst of many X's." Another metaphorical use of "buzzing with" is to mean "being discussed by many people." In this case, I suspect that the two metaphors were being compounded to mean

> Many of those in the Richmond Coliseum were discussing the many possible outcomes of the upcoming game.

Sports reporting is really not intended to provoke deep analysis. All that was really meant was

> Before the game, people were talking excitedly.